# Trying to read div tags individually both share same class in a meteor JS Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

Using {{for each}} handlebar to iterate over MongoDB Collection in Meteor JS.Data displayed fine inside buttons.

Issue is how to read text associated with button of class btn-correctOption.
because of #each I have more than one button associated with class btn-correctOption.

1. quizDisplaySection.js File

   quizDisplaySection Template

   ```
   <template name="quizDisplaySection">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <ul>{{#each questions}}
                       <br>{{> question}}
                       <br>{{/each}}</ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </template>
   ```
2. Question Template File

   ```
   <template name="question">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-quiz" disabled>{{Quiz}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-option">{{Option1}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-option">{{Option2}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-option">{{Option3}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-option">{{Option4}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-correctOption hide">{{OptionCorrect}}</button>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <hr width="75%">
           </div>
       </div>
   </template>
   ```

   I am trying to read value of button of class btn-correctOption,but I have more than one button with class btn-correctOption because of #each template rendering.

3.quizDisplaySection.js

```
"click .btn-option": function(evt,tmp){
    var qds_correctOption = $(".btn-correctOption").text();
    alert(qds_correctOption);       
}
```

qds_correctOption give me string whic is combined value of all the text in the button with class btn-correctOption.any way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `template.$(selector)`:

> Find all elements matching selector in this template instance,
>   and
>   return them as a JQuery object.

```
Template.question.events({
  'click .btn-option': function(evt, tmp) {
    var current_option = $(evt.currentTarget).text();
    var qds_correctOption = tmp.$(".btn-correctOption").text();
    console.log(current_option, qds_correctOption);   
  }
});
```

Comment: Max I appreciate the response ,but still I am getting a JQuery object with combined content for eg qds_correctOption give value SamsungApple, I want a way to seperate Samsung and Apple and store them seperately as diffrent variable

Comment: With for each same class name of dom elements ie buttons , so any way i can display elements from collection using for each and then get different value based on  which button i click

Comment: It seems feasible for me. Confirm that the click event is inside `Template.question.events`, not inside `Template.quizDisplaySection.events`. Yes you can get different value based on which button you click, just using `event.currentTarget`. Review my new edit.

Comment: Correct Mate , key point is to move code to `Template.question.events` and it started working like we want , Always appreciating your help :) Thank you sir